# Mysql Update с помощью переменных

Tags: mysql, node.js

как реализовать следующий mysql запрос?
var sql = "UPDATE some_table SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?";

Я сделал так, но не заработало....

con.query(sql, [some_set_key, some_set_value, some_id_value], (err, res) => {
// code
})

```
var update_user_data = JSON.parse(chunk);
                   for (var key in update_user_data) {
                       var set_key = key, set_value = "";
                       if (key == "firstName") {
                           set_value = update_user_data["firstName"]
                       };
                       if (key == "lastName") {
                           set_value = update_user_data["lastName"]
                       };
                       if (key == "mail") {
                           set_value = update_user_data["mail"]
                       };
                       if (key == "password") {
                           set_value = update_user_data["password"]
                       };

                       var whering = baseData[0].id;

                       var update_all_users_data_sql = "UPDATE slide_tab SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?"

                       console.log(baseData[0].id);
                       con.query(update_all_users_data_sql, [set_key, set_value], [wheringId], (err, result) => {
                           if (err) throw err;
                           console.log("USER datas have updated");
                           res.end();
                       });
                   }
```

Comment: И возможно ли такое?

Comment: Такой запрос невозможен. Вы пытаетесь имя колонки запроса вставить как параметр.  А все параметры экранируются. Попробуйте ради примера сделать такой запрос прям в БД `SELECT * FROM 'table'`. Будет ошибка

Answer (score 0):

`query()` метод - 1-ый аргумент - строка с запросом, второй - колбэк функция

То есть:

```
con.query("SELECT foo FROM bar", (err, res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

В вашем случае можно:

```
con.query({
    sql: update_all_users_data_sql
},
[set_key, set_value, wheringId],
(err, res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: мне нужно сделать апдейт, не селект.

Comment: без разницы, запрос - есть запрос

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan обновил ответ

Comment: con.query({
                               sql: update_all_users_data_sql,
                               values: [set_key, set_value, where_key, whering]
                           }, (err, result) => {
                               if (err) throw err;
                               console.log("USER datas have updated");
                               res.end();
                           }); вот так сделал

Comment: выдало такую ошибку

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''firstName' = 'Borat' WHERE 'id' = 1' at line 1

Comment: Скопируйте как я написал выше.

Comment: тa же самая ошибка... Кстати, я тоже так делал, за исключением того, что первый аргумент не в виде объекта..

Answer (score 0):

В SQL нельзя передавать имена колонок (так же как и других объектов БД) в виде переменных. Они должны быть указаны непосредственно в тексте запроса. Поэтому надо построить строку запроса самостоятельно так, что бы в ней оказались нужные имена, в таком виде `update table set x=?, y=? ...`. Я бы сделал это примерно так:

```
var names=[];  // Массив с именами полей (и плейсхолдерами, в виде "x=?")
var values=[]; // Массив значений для передачи в query
for (var key in ['firstName', 'lastName', 'mail', 'password']) {
    if(update_user_data[key] !== undefined) {
        names.push(key+'=?');
        values.push(update_user_data[key]);
    }
}

var update_all_users_data_sql = "UPDATE slide_tab SET " + names.join(',') + " WHERE id=?";
values.push(baseData[0].id); // Добавляем значение для where
con.query(update_all_users_data_sql, values, ....);
```